# $f$ is derivable on $[-1,1]$, $M=\sup |f' |$, if exist $a \in (0,1), \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 0$, prove $\lvert \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \rvert \le M(1-a^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Firstly I found that $$M(1-a^2) = 2 \times \sup\lvert f'\rvert \int_1^a x \,dx $$
so I went to find out the connection between $\int_a^1 f(x) \, dx$ and $\int_a^1 xf'(x) \, dx$,

then I got $$\left. \int_a^1 f(x) \, dx = xf(x)\right|_{a}^{b} - \int_a^1 xf'(x)\,dx$$

At this time I realized that I went the wrong way.

Then I let $g(x) = \int_{-1}^x f(x) \, dx$, easily know that $g(-a) = g(a), g(-1) = 0$
\begin{align}
g(1)-g(a) &= f(\xi)(1-a),  \xi \in (a,1)\\
g(-a)-g(-1)&=f(\eta)(1-a),\eta \in (-1,-a)
\end{align}

By adding them I got $$\lvert g(1)\rvert = \left| \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx \right| =\lvert f(\xi) + f(\eta) \rvert (1-a)$$

From this I knew I can prove $\lvert \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx \rvert \le 2M(1-a)$ but still don't know how to prove that $\lvert \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx \rvert \le M(1-a^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 0$ implies that there is a $x_0 \in (-a, a)$ with $f(x_0) = 0$. Using $|f'(x)| \le M$ we get
$$
 |f(x)| = |f(x) - f(x_0) |\le M |x-x_0|
$$
for all $x \in [-1, 1]$. Then
$$
I_1 = \int_a^1 |f(x)| \, dx \le M \int_a^1 (x-x_0) \, dx
$$
and 
$$
I_2 = \int_{-1}^{-a} |f(x)| \, dx \le M \int_{-1}^{-a} (x_0-x ) \, dx  = M \int_a^1 (x_0+x) \, dx
$$
so that
$$
 I_1 + I_2 \le M \int_a^1 2x \, dx = M(1-a^2) \, .
$$ 
This gives the desired estimate because 
$$
\left\lvert \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \right\rvert =
\left\lvert \int_{-1}^{-a} f(x) dx  + \int_{a}^1 f(x) dx\right\rvert \\
\le \int_{-1}^{-a} |f(x)| \, dx + \int_a^1 |f(x)| \, dx   = I_1 + I_2 \,.
$$